# text not aligned on the right in article

Tags: line-breaking

I'm writing in article mode and some lines in certain paragraphs stick out on the right. I read online that LaTeX by default aligns text on both left and right - but it doesn't seem to be the case? Here's the code I'm using. Thanks!

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{color}
\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=1.5in,bottom=1.5in}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{sgame}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{footnote}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
    \addtocounter{footnote}{+1}%
    \endgroup
}

\makesavenoteenv{tabular}
\makesavenoteenv{table}

\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\makeatother
\begin{document}


I'm writing in article mode and some lines in certain paragraphs stick out on the right. I read online that LaTeX by default aligns text on both left and right. I read online that LaTeX by default aligns text on both left and right - but it doesn't seem to be the case?

As an illustration, two big-budget action movies stood out in summer 2015 : Paramount's {\em Terminator: Genesys} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: What exactly should be wrong with this example? BTW: ae and aecompl has not been nedded for 10 years or so.

Comment: just edited and added more paragraphs to show the issue - as you can see the second paragraph, first line, sticks outside of the right margin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break the word manually

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{color}
\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=1.5in,bottom=1.5in}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{sgame}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{footnote}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
    \addtocounter{footnote}{+1}%
    \endgroup
}

\makesavenoteenv{tabular}
\makesavenoteenv{table}

\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\makeatother
\begin{document}


I'm writing in article mode and some lines in certain paragraphs stick out on the right. I read online that LaTeX by default aligns text on both left and right. I read online that LaTeX by default aligns text on both left and right - but it doesn't seem to be the case?

As an illustration, two big-budget action movies stood out in summer 2015 : Para\-mount's {\em Terminator: Genesys} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Such cases happen not often, so I think doing things manually is not a big deal.

Answer (score 2):

TeX does its best, but some words slip through its hyphenation mechanism. One of these is *paramount*.

The word is listed in `ushyphex.tex`, a big file with hyphenation exceptions for uncommon words and also a few of common ones that don't get hyphenated properly.

The entry lists `para-mount` as the possible hyphenation; adding `\hyphenation{para-mount}` in the preamble will do.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=1.5in,bottom=1.5in}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{sgame}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{hyperref} % should be last


\pagestyle{plain}

\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
    \addtocounter{footnote}{+1}%
    \endgroup
}

\makesavenoteenv{tabular}
\makesavenoteenv{table}

%\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\hyphenation{para-mount}
% maybe also \input{ushyphex}`


\begin{document}

I'm writing in article mode and some lines in certain paragraphs stick out on the right. 
I read online that LaTeX by default aligns text on both left and right. I read online 
that LaTeX by default aligns text on both left and right - but it doesn't seem to 
be the case?

As an illustration, two big-budget action movies stood out in summer 2015: 
Paramount's \emph{Terminator: Genesys} 

\end{document}
```

Inputting `\ushyphex` and loading `microtype` might be sufficient (or adding manually some exceptions as done in the example code). However this is not guaranteed to solve all paragraph typesetting: if a line is overfull nonetheless, rewording is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for this helpful info - yes there are a few other words that had this issue in my 50-page document. Makes sense!